# Can the Xamarin Dependency service work if the caller is not using Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Simple question, can the Xamarin.Forms Dependency Service still Get the platform of the caller if the caller is not Xamarin.Forms based or even Xamarin at all?

Now for the setup to the question. I have two app projects, Android and Windows UWP. For various reasons, I don't need iOS and I cannot use Xamarin.Forms for the two. So, I have a native UWP application and Xamarin.Android. These two can still share a lot of code with PCL or better, .NetStandard.

If I am creating libraries, as I am loosely following this post [Dependency Service](https://wolfprogrammer.com/2016/08/05/dependency-services-with-xamarin-forms/) , and the caller of a library like this is Xamarin.Android or UWP (ie not Xamarin Forms) will the Dependency Service in the library still know the platform of the caller? The bottom line is, in the library, I need to know what platform is consuming or calling the library so I can do platform specific code within the library.

As a follow up to this question, a lot of the examples I have seen with Dependency Service use a PCL. Since everybody seems to be moving away from PCL and towards .NetStandard libraries, can this same thing be achieved if the library is .NetStandard?

Thanks!

Comment: `so I can do platform specific code within the library` Does not make sense if you are using PCL/NetStd libraries as they are, per definition, platform independent. But. if you need to know the platform of the caller, then pass it within a parameter of the method or .ctor, or set a public static var from UWP/Android. Can you use `DependencyService.cs` without Forms, sure, it is a very simple attribute-based DI service, you can pull the code (and attributes) from the githib repo
`

Comment: In a normal use case you have an Interface in a shared PCL and the concrete implementations are done in platform code. In forms  Almost all of the code can be done in the PCL so its important that a DI service exists to get the platform implementations where needed ... Since I don't see how you could be putting any UI in a . net standard library that's shared without some absurd work. You need to separate some concerns.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. Let me clarify, as I am following the link provided in my post, I mis-spoke. The .NetStandard or PCL library will be platform independent. However, in the solution that I am creating the library, I will ALSO have an Android class library and a UWP class library. I will have an interface in the PCL library that the platform specific libraries will implement. This is where I will do the platform specific code (ie accessing the file system). So, following this common pattern, I was just wondering how to do DI or IoC (are they the same?) if not using Xamarin.forms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using the Xamarin Forms library, then you will not have access to the `DependencyService` class.

You can use one of the many other DI libraries such as [Autofac](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac) which is compatible with .NET Standard projects.